# What password is sent when a router does not have a password set?

Tags: network, wifi, password, airport, swift

I promise this is not a hypothetical question. I am trying to use this GitHub repo - https://github.com/braineo/airport-bssid

The latest OS X version does not allow specifying the BSSID so I am using a SSID / channel workaround. However, the router I am trying to connect to is open and does not have a password (I don't have any way of disabling).

Thus the script requests "Input WiFi password" and nothing works. I have tried [no entry] and hitting enter, a pair of quotes ""+enter, [one space]+enter.

Happy to hear and try some other ideas. Thanks!

Comment: This probably is a question for the developer of the application. There already seems to be an issue for this on GitHub (https://github.com/braineo/airport-bssid/issues/6).

Answer (score 2):

The program does not currently support networks without passwords.

You can amend the program to fix that by editing the source code file `/bssid/connect-ssid.swift`. You'll want to remove lines 42 and 43:

```
print("Input WiFi password")
let password = String(cString: getpass(""))
```

And replace them with:

```
let password: String? = nil
```